# Shell-style list generation or variable expression in Python?

Tags: python, variables

----Complete Rephrasing----

I was working on a new class where each instance was essentially sequential and linked.  I had thought, in a very shell scripty way, that I could define a function to compile a list of all of these instances if I named them systematically.  Then  I could do what I wanted in the first place, which was navigate through the sequence in some way.

But I see that this is a awful approach.  As I understand it now, I should do one of the following instead:

- Include embedded references in the class and thereby create a recursive data structure.
- Create a list of all of the instances, which is perhaps updated in the class **init** or when a new instance is made.
- Forget defining a new class in the first place and use a list of other objects.

I hope I've got that straight.  Thanks again for the advice.

-----Original but edited generalized question-----

Hello,

I'm relatively new to Python and I find myself always wanted to generate a list of existing objects of some kind.  Say I had three variables named x# where # is a number from 1 to 3.  The sort of code I feel tempted to write would be something like:

```
n=1
List_Of_X=[]
while n < 4:
  List_Of_X.append("x%s" % (n))
  n += 1
```

But then of course I end up with a list of strings rather than variables.  So, is there any way to 'express' the variables corresponding to the strings?  Or better yet, create a list of variables in the first place?

Edit:  The crux was not specifying a list manually - I wanted somehow to automate that.  It seems from the answers below that I can use my admittedly crummy method above to generate a list of strings, then use the eval() function to express them.  Or, use a somewhat complex method of generating a list of objects in the first place.

I get the feeling that either solutions are probably not the best practices but I appreciate all the help!  Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have variables named `x1`, `x2`, etc. in the first place?  Just use a list.

Comment: what are you really trying to do

Comment: The mystery is solved in the comments for the accepted answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you first need to understand that there are no variables in Python. There are only references to objects. So it is a mistake to even think about "creating variables". They don't exist.

Comment: Interesting comment, I've never heard about this before.

Comment: "There are no variables in Python" is pedantic and confusing.

Comment: This is downright incorrect. There are variables, by any definition (other than one that exclude mutable variables).

Comment: @Marcin Of a different kind. When coming to Python from other languages it helps to re-think what a "variable" is. Hence I make a statement like this to prod in that direction. In python, they don't exist in the way other languages have them.

Comment: @Keith python variables are entirely like the variables you will be familiar with from visual basic, java, C++, common lisp, or scheme. The only difference is how they come into existence.

Comment: @Marcin Nope. Python variables have no type.

Comment: @Keith Really? You think that makes them not variables? Note also that untyped (or polymorphically typed) variables exist in visual basic, C++, common lisp, and scheme. Java variables are weakly typed. So, once again, not a massive departure.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
list_of_x = [x1, x2, x3]
```

Comment: Sorry, I was a little unclear about this.  I wanted to avoid specifying the list explicitly  - thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you have code like this:

```
x1 = "foo"
x2 = "bar"
x3 = "goat"
```

then you should replace it with:

```
x = ["foo", "bar", "goat"]
```

You could do:

```
x = [x1, x2, x3]
```

But that will copy the values from x1,x2, x3 into x. Changes made to x will not change x1, x2, x3.

If this strategy doesn't work for you, you need to show us more of what you are doing so we can help you.

Comment: Ah, more evidence that I should have made it more explicit that I wanted to avoid manually typing in the list of 'x'!  Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vars()`, `locals()`, or `globals()` to create new variables, although needing to do this is pretty unusual:

```
for n in range(1, 4):
    vars()['x%s' % n] = n

>>> x1, x2, x3
<<< (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Ahh I see - first I've heard of the vars function and I didn't realize the locals or globals functions would operate this way.  Thanks, between this method and Jeff Chen's answer I can see solutions to my problem from two different directions.

Comment: @Kyle: **WRONG WAY GO BACK** ... tell us *with* some clarity what your **real** problem is ... vars() and eval() cause more problems than they solve!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so part of the mystery seems to be capturing your variables x1, x2, ... when they spring into existence. If you manage to do that it should be easy to collect them in a list, right?! So you have to hunt for the place where you actually assign them a value, `x1 = ...`, `x2 = ...` ...

Maybe you are reading those values from a file, or from user input?! - Let's elaborate one case that Eevee mentioned in a comment, where x1, x2, ... are actually instances of a user-defined class. Then, rather than appending manually to a list after the assignment of one of your xN, you can let the class do the recording for you:

```
class C(object):
    instances = []
    def __init__(self):
        C.instances.append(self)

x1=C()
x2=C()
x3=C()

C.instances # <= [<__main__.C object at 0x01293230>, ...]
```

So you captured the *values* of x1, x2, ... in a nice list. Does that help?

Answer (score -3):

you can convert a variable to its value by using eval(var)

For example, in your case you could do:

```
map(eval,List_Of_X)
```

if you wanted to convert your list of strings ['x1','x2',...] into their values, say [1,2,...] if x1=1 and x2=2

Comment: Pleae don't do this.  `eval` is virtually never the right answer to any problem, and it's dangerous besides.  If nothing else, use `globals()` and friends.  Ideally, just don't create variables with these names in the first place.

Comment: @Kyle What you need is a better data structure, not an `eval` hack.

Comment: @Eevee @FMc Can you guys elaborate on why eval is dangerous/hackish?

Comment: Please yes, I'd appreciate advice on doing this in a more "Pythonic" way.

Comment: @Kyle The real point here is not to create `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` in the first place. Instead store your data in a proper container -- a `list` in this case. Lists are designed to solve precisely the problem that variables like `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` create. Using `eval` might "work" in some narrow sense, but it will send you down a path that is inherently difficult to maintain, debug, etc. In addition, if performance/speed is an issue for your application, `eval` is a loser.

Comment: @Kyle, in several places here, you've said you want to avoid "specifying the list manually".  Why?  Where are `x1` and friends actually coming from?  Re `eval`, it's compiling new code in a language that can already modify itself, which signifies a very bad design somewhere.

Comment: @John @Eevee:  The question stemmed from wanting to iterate over all instances of a user-defined class.  So I had thought that if I named the instances systematically, I could write a shell-like loop to compile a list of them.  But it seems that I should just define a list in the first place that contains the instances and append it as new instances are made?

Comment: Yes, do exactly that!  If it's inherent to the functioning of the class, you could even append to a class-level list within `__init__` and have the work done for you.  And in general, please include the original context with questions like this, so you don't get half a dozen geeks chasing their tails.  :)  (see also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: Done - though I hope these comments are sufficiently visible as they contain the real meat of the thread!